# (Re)enable remote destkop on win 10

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

[image]

How do I enable that?
The device is connected to an AD but I have local admin privileges.

I tried:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'-name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0
```

Also enabled `Allow users to connect remotely using Remote Desktop Services` in group policy.

And the network is a private one.

why is this still greyed out / disabled?

Comment: The obvious question is your device connected to an AD domain? If it’s not then you have disabled a required setting necessary for you to enable this feature. It could be a setting or a related domain policy. Try switching the network profile from private to public.

Comment: sounds similar to https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2218089-has-anyone-encounter-this-with-remote-desktop

Comment: yes it is connected to an AD but changing the network profile did not change anything